# Heuristics for the minimum-weight $k$-clique problem

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, clique, heuristics

Hello
Does someone have an idea for heuristics for the problem:

> Given undirected weighted(weights on edges) complete
>   graph $G(V,E)[|V|=n,|E| = m]$, find a clique of size $k < n$(k is number of nodes) having
>   the minimum weight.

I have searched for minclique problem but it doesn't really answer my question.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is k part of the input or a fixed constant?

Comment: its part of the input

Comment: weights on edges or vertices ?

Comment: @Suresh: wieghts on edges

Comment: please edit the problem defn to incorporate this.

Comment: How big are the $k$, $m$ and $n$ you have in mind? Do your weights satisfy any nice properties such as density (i.e. max weight = O(sum of weights / $n^2$))? Your problem sounds like it's a weighted version of the densest subgraph problem, so you may wish to search for algorithms for that problem for ideas.

Comment: @Warren Schudy Maybe I have not searched right but what I have found talks about maximum and not minimum. Please correct me if I wrong.

Comment: @Yakov, for the algorithms that I know of, all you have to do is flip the signs of all weights to find the minimum weight clique. For example, all the papers I'm on that say anything about "maximum weight triangle" are equally valid when maximum is replaced with minimum. (The algorithms have to change only mildly.)

Comment: @Yakov: as Ryan said it's easy to convert between minimization and maximization by just flipping the signs of the weights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem appears to be the minimization variant (flip the edge weight signs?) of the edge-weighted maximal clique problem. Check out this reference:

> @article{park1996extended,
>   title={{An extended formulation
>   approach to the edge-weighted maximal
>   clique problem}},
>   author={Park, K.
>   and Lee, K. and Park, S.},
>   journal={European Journal of
>   Operational Research},
>   volume={95}, 
>   number={3},
>   pages={671--682},
>   year={1996},
>   publisher={Elsevier} }

where they discuss various LP-based heuristics.

Comment: The lp-heuristics is too slow but i will look for other algorithms